# Dplyr count() function is returning the wrong results

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a very large dataframe from a csv file. The dataframe has its `fill` property set to true (just mentioning this in case it's useful to know it) so there's some cells which have no values.

Now, I have a function which takes a DF, and is supposed to group the row by the `Match.Flag` column, then count the amount of Y and N matches and return the resulting DF.

So if I have a total of 15 records, where 10 records have `Match.Flag = 'Y'` and 5 records have `Match.Flag` = 'N', I want to return a DF that would look like the following

```
Match.Flag | Count | Rate
     "Y"       10    66.66
     "N"       5     33.33
```

The code I'm trying is

```
calculateMatchRate <- function(df) {
  groupings <- df %>% group_by(Match.Flag) %>% tally()
  return(groupings)
}
```

However, the resulting DF is not throwing correct values at all, for either column.

```
Match.Flag     n
   <chr>      <int>
 1 ""          4587
 2 "03"           2
 3 "0307"         1
 4 "04"           2
 5 "06"           2
 6 "08"           2
 7 "0805"         1
 8 "11"           1
 9 "14"           7
10 "19"           3
```

My file only has 2 values in Match.Flag: either Y or N, there's no nulls in it either. The file is being correctly loaded as far as I can tell, it's a tab delimited file with some cells in blank. Loaded with the following code:

```
myFile <- data.frame(read.table(file = path, header = TRUE, sep="\t", fill=TRUE))
```

I am aware that my code does not yet includes the `Rate` column seen in the example. It would be good to know how to create it, but let's not consider it part of the main question and for now lets focus on simply counting the amount of Ys or Ns in `Match.Flag`

According to the [dplyr docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/tally.html), `df %>% group_by() %>% tally()` should get the job done. I've also tried just using `df %>% count(Match.Flag)` but it also returns the wrong results.

What is happening here?

df for MRE

```
df <- data.frame("Match.Flag" = c('Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N'), "Names" = c("John", "James", "Mark", "Maria", "Erika", "Gulliver")
```

Comment: With your example, it is giving 2, 4 for `count(df, Match.Flag)`.  It is better to check whether there are leading/lagging spaces. i.e. `df %>% mutate(Match.Flag = trimws(Match.Flag)) %>% count(Match.Flag)`

Comment: Then it is most likely something from my source file, however, I cannot upload it to SF because it has confidential data, asides from it being huge.

I just tried that code you provided and the results seem to indicate that it is taking completely different fields from other columns and for some reason considering them as Match.Flag values. The output is displaying several values from other columns as being part of the Match.Flag column.

Comment: Upon checking the result of the uploaded file, it seems like the empty cells are completely messing up with the layout. Is there a safer way to handle missing values?

Comment: You don't need additional `data.frame` call after `read.table` . `myFile <- read.table(file = path, header = TRUE, sep="\t", fill=TRUE)` is enough. After doing that what does `unique(myFile$Match.Flag)` return?

Comment: It returns an obscene amount of values. it is taking values that should belong to other columns and placing them in Match.Flag
The file itself is properly delimited. I can take it and paste it in Excel and, while it almost collapses it from the size, it does displays everything correctly. So this is R not reading the blank values properly.

Comment: In that case I think you have not read your data properly. Maybe you have different separator. Check `ncol(myFile)`, is it correct and as expected?

Comment: No, it says NULL. 
The delimiter in the field is correct. It is a tab delimited file. The delimiter I'm indicating is \t which should indeed correspond to tab delimited. Also, when pasting the data into excel, selecting the Text to Columns option only produces the proper results when I select to delimit it by Tab, so it is a tab delimited file.

The only thing I could thing about is that, despite being tab delimited, the extension of the file itself is .csv. I will change the extension to txt to see if that changes anything.

Comment: So I got a warning showing `Warning message: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :   EOF within quoted string`

This file does not have any quoted strings. I added  quote = "" to parameters and while it is no longer showing the warning, it still says ncol is NULL

Comment: If `ncol(myFile)` returns `NULL` something is already wrong in reading the file. What is `class(myFile)` ? So we don't actually know how your data is saved to suggest you how to accurately read it. But it is clear that problem is in reading the data and not the code that you have written.

Comment: Sorry, the NULL was actually a result of me writing the code wrong, I was writing ncol(df$Match.Flag) because I was previously trying to read Match.Flag only and forgot to remove that. It is now correctly returning 173 columns

However, the problem persists. And I attempted to create a new DF that consists only of the Match.Flag column and print it, and it's showing that there's several empty rows. This makes no sense since the file does not have any empty rows for match flag. Every Match flag must be either N or Y. i already confirmed it through Excel filters as well.

Comment: The class of myFile is data.frame